# Angular 2, getting html content using http.get and a route as url

Tags: angular

I was trying to get the html content from one of my components using http.get, this is my code.

```
let myRoute = 'http://localhost/mycomponent'
let response = this.http.get(myRoute).map(res => res.text())
    response.subscribe( 
        res => console.log(res)
    )
```

I always get this: GET http://localhost/mycomponent 404 (Not Found), but myRoute is valid route, if I copy the value from the console and paste in the browser it works.

Comment: Are you trying to just get the HTML/text content of the template file to parse it or do something to it?  I'm confused at what you're going for. URLs as they appear in the browser don't always translate to actual file paths, and in the case of single page apps like Angular, they almost never do, as Angular Router uses the Location service to rewrite URLs dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain I understand what you are trying to accomplish.

The `http.get` is required to get data from a back-end server. That back-end server would have code in ASP.NET or PHP or node.js. You can't call an Angular component using that syntax.

If you simply want to pass data from one component to the next, there are many ways to do that including using routing parameters and building a service.

To navigate to another route, use the `routerLink` directive or `this.router.navigate()`.

Consider working through the Angular tutorial here https://angular.io/tutorial to better understand how Angular routing and data retrieval work.